# How to iterate through JSON object in handlebar

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to make a GET request and want to output the query that been sent.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
var myQuery = req.query;
console.log(myQuery);
res.render('home', myQuery);});
```

After I submit a query and I console log the query, I get

```
Express started on http://localhost:5200; press Ctrl-C to terminate.
{ parameter1: 'value1',
  parameter2: 'value2',
  parameter3: 'value3' }
```

in the handlebar file, i do

```
<ul>
{{#each this}}
<li> {{@key}}:{{@value}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul
```

When I render an HTML code, I get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li> settings:</li>
<li> parameter1:</li>
<li> parameter2:</li>
<li> parameter3:</li>
<li> _locals:</li>
<li> cache:</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting the body to look like this

```
 <body>
    <ul>
    <li> parameter1:value1</li>
    <li> parameter2:value2</li>
    <li> parameter3:value3</li>
    </ul>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

I replaced the code in my handlebars file with

```
{{#each myData}}
<li> {{@key}} : {{@this}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

and I rendered the query as

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var myQuery = req.query;
    console.log(myQuery);
    res.render('home', {myData:myQuery});

});
```